# Does anyone used azure ad b2c login with react native

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

Help on to create react-native app with azure b2c login, we are struggling to create an app with azure b2c login in react native

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very generic, I also can only point you to a few resources that should help:

msal for react-native libray: https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal

alternativle you can use https://github.com/GSingh01/ad-b2c-react-native with a full sample at https://github.com/michaelburch/react-native-aad-b2c-sample

Comment: Sadly the react-native-msal library is archived on github. The library you linked is also not very well maintained and the sample is using a VERY old version of that library. It seems that not many are using azure ad b2c with react native after all...

Comment: I think `react-native-msal` is still the best option. But it requires a small patch described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77819914/911408