# How can I add Microsoft authentication to my react native app?

Tags: react-native, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a React-Native application in development that is an extension of a current web application. The web application makes use of MSAL to authenticate the users and I want to do this as well with the mobile app.

I have not really managed to find anything relevant, and what I have found was out of date or for the ReactJS framework.

I have been trying to make use of the MSAL-react-native component however it isn't that well documented so I'm lost over there as well

Comment: Have you looked at https://microsoft.github.io/rnx-kit/docs/tools/react-native-test-app-msal perhaps you can use this as a template?

Comment: @ErikKinstler "Page Not Found" error, the link is broken ❌

Answer (score 1):

Use [react-native-msal](https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal) for Microsoft authentication

Comment: I have been trying to use this framework but since it's been deprecated I'm still looking into other options. Not to mention that it isn't well documented

Comment: this repo is not very old, I guess you can use it and after several months find a new solution (sometimes good people create the fork). For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sconnelley/react-native-msal

Answer (score 1):

In January 2024 I still find that [react-native-msal](https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal)
 is the most pragmatic option for React Native even though it was archived in May 2022.

---

Here is the fix I had to make in Android gradle file inside the library:

```
// node_modules/react-native-msal/android/build.gradle

...

compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('Msal_compileSdkVersion', 33) // 29 → 33
defaultConfig {
  minSdkVersion safeExtGet('Msal_minSdkVersion', 21) // 16 → 21
  targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('Msal_targetSdkVersion', 33) // 29 → 33
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
}

...

dependencies {
  // noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' // From node_modules
  implementation('com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:2.2.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.microsoft.device.display' // This group is obsolete nowadays
  }
}
```

To create the patch I used the [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) utility:

```
npx patch-package react-native-msal
```

---

If I had more time, I'd implement a custom [bridge](https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios) that wraps the native MSAL libraries.

Answer (score -3):

Enable authentication in your own React Application by using Azure Active Directory B2C:

[image]

For more information please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-react-spa-app

Comment: It is not for react native